# Wrong order of execution async handler

Tags: dart, async-await

I have small app that execute requests to external service.

```
  final app = Alfred();
  app.post('/ctr', (req, res) async { // complex tender request
    var data = await req.body;
    await complexTendexAPIRequest(data as Map<String, dynamic>);
    print('Hello World');
    await res.json({'data': 'ok'});
  });
```

Handler code:

```
complexTendexAPIRequest(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
  print('Request: $data');
  try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(COMPLEX_URL),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN'},
        body: json.encode(data)
      );

      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        var res = json.decode(response.body);
        int latestId = res['id'];
        String url = 'https://api.ru/v2/complex/status?id=$latestId';
        stdout.write('Waiting for "complete" status from API: ');
        Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
          final response = await http.get(
            Uri.parse(url),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN'}
          );

          var data = json.decode(response.body);
          if(data['status'] == 'completed') {
            timer.cancel();
            stdout.write('[DONE]');
            stdout.write('\nFetching result: ');
            String url = "https://api.ru/v2/complex/results?id=$latestId";
            final response = await http.get(
              Uri.parse(url),
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN'}
            );
            stdout.write('[DONE]');
            var data = prettyJson(json.decode(response.body));
            await File('result.json').writeAsString(data.toString());
            print("\nCreating dump of result: [DONE]");
          }
          
        });
        
      }
      else {
        print('[ERROR] Wrong status code for complex request. StatusCode: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
  } 
  on SocketException catch(e) {
    print('No Internet connection: $e');
  } on TimeoutException catch(e) {
    print('TenderAPI Timeout: $e');
  } on Exception catch(e) {
    print('Some unknown Exception: $e');
  }

}
```

But output is very strange it's look like it's do not waiting `complexTendexAPIRequest` completion and go forward:

```
Waiting for "complete" status from API: Hello World
[DONE]
Fetching result: [DONE]
Creating dump of result: [DONE]
```

But should be:

```
Waiting for "complete" status from API: [DONE]
Fetching result: [DONE]
Creating dump of result: [DONE]
Hello World
```

I suppose that reason can be in `Timer.periodic` but how to fix it to get expected order and execution of:

```
    print('Hello World');
    await res.json({'data': 'ok'});
```

only after `complexTendexAPIRequest` completed.

upd: I rewrote code to `while` loop:
https://gist.github.com/bubnenkoff/fd6b4f0d7aeae7007680e7902fbdc1e9
it's seems that it's ok.

Alfred https://github.com/rknell/alfred

Comment: Please give more detail on what you want to talk about, so that the viewers may understand better.

Comment: @MikeOsborn I've added example of what I expect.

Comment: If you want to wait until all your tries have been dealt with, you don't want `Timer.periodic`, you want a loop.

Comment: @nvoigt explain please why? I need to check external api periodically to get `complete` status. In `while` loop I would need add some pause between every check.

Comment: But you want to wait for it to be finished here, right? That is your whole problem, that you don't wait for it, you just start a timer and then your program continues on without waiting for it.

Comment: The timer is meant to give you independent timer ticks. You don't want that. You want to be in control of what happens, and wait for it.

Comment: @nvoigt do not understand... where and how I should do wait?

Comment: Your comment says you wait for a correct answer of the periodic service call. But you don't actually do that. You don't wait. You schedule this code to fire every second and then proceed. You realize that Timer.periodic does not wait for anything, right? It just schedules it and then happily moves on. That's why I said you don't want a periodic thing going behind the scenes, you want a loop, that you can control and wait for.

Comment: @nvoigt just while loop? Or loop with some sleep to prevent to many calls?

Comment: That's up to you. If you want to wait a second between calls you can do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238093/discussion-between-dmitry-bubnenkov-and-nvoigt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `Timer.periodic`, as others have pointed out.

You do:

```dart
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
    // do something ...
  });
```

That sets up a timer, then immediately continues execution.
The timer triggers every second, calls the *async* callback (which returns a future that no-one ever waits for) and which does something which just might take longer than a second.

You can convert this to a normal loop, basically:

```dart
  while (true) {
    // do something ...
    if (data['status'] == 'completed') {
      // ...
      break;
    } else {
      // You can choose your own delay here, doesn't have
      // to be the same one every time.
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    }
  }
```

If you still want it to be timer driven, with fixed ticks, consider rewriting this as:

```dart
await for (var _ in Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1))) {
  // do something ...
  // Change `timer.cancel();` to a `break;` at the end of the block.
}
```

Here you create a stream which fires an event every second. Then you use an `await for` loop to wait for each steam event. If the thing you do inside the loop is asynchronous (does an `await`) then you are even ensured that the next stream event is delayed until the loop body is done, so you won't have two fetches running at the same time.
*And* if the code throws, the error will be caught by the surrounding `try`/`catch`, which I assume was intended, rather than being an uncaught error ending up in the `Future` that no-one listens to.

If you want to retain the `Timer.periodic` code, you can, but you need to do something extra to synchronize it with the `async`/`await` code around it (which only really understands futures and streams, not timers).
For example:

```dart
var timerDone = Completer();
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
  try {
    // do something ...
    // Add `timerDone.complete();` next to `timer.cancel()`.
  } catch (e, s) {
    timer.cancel();
    timerDone.completeError(e, s);
  }
});
await timerDone.future;
```

This code uses a `Completer` to complete a future and effectively bridge the gap between timers and futures that can be awaited (one of the listed uses of `Completer` in the documentation).
You may still risk the timer running concurrently if one step takes longer than a second.

Also, you can possibly use the [`retry`](https://pub.dev/packages/retry) package, if it's the same thing you want to retry until it works.